# Populating SubModels using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of object which is something like this

```
[Code Type][condition Type][Question Type][Description]
[A1][C1][q1][dC1]
[A1][C1][q2][dC1]
[A1][C1][q3][dC1]
[B1][C2][q4][dC2]
[B1][C2][q5][dC2]
[B1][C2][q6][dC2]
[B1][C3][q7][dC3]
[B1][C3][q8][dC3]
[B1][C3][q9][dc3]
```

I want to map this with a class which has a subclass and it's subclass also has a subclass. 
Structure is like this

```
public Class TypeModel
{
    public string Type{get;set;}
    public List<ConditionModel> Conditions {get;set;}
}

public Class ConditionModel
{
    public string Type{get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
    public List<QuestionModel> Questions {get;set;}
}

public Class QuestionModel
{
    public string Type {get;set;}
}
```

I have written this LINQ query to populate the main Type Class so far but it is not working. I need help in creating this query.

```
var results = allTypes.GroupBy(type => type.CodeType)
                .Select(grp => new TypeModel
                {
                    Type = grp.Select(i => i.CodeType).First(),
                    Conditions = new List<ConditionModel>
                    {
                        grp.GroupBy(condition => condition.ConditionType)
                        .Select(conditionGrp => new ConditionModel {
                              Type = conditionGrp.Select(i => i.ConditionType).First(),
                              Description = conditionGrp.Select(i => i.Description).First(),
                              Questions = new List<QuestionModel>
                              {
                                  conditionGrp.GroupBy(question => question.QuestionType)
                                  .Select(questionGrp => new QuestionModel
                                  {
                                      Type = questionGrp.Select(i => i.QuestionType).First(),
                                  })
                              }
                        })
                    }
                });
```

What I am trying to achieve with this query?  To get list of TypeModel. 
If you'll notice the table first three rows will fetch me one typeModel and another 6 rows another typeModel but it will have two ConditonModels and each condition Model,  3 questionModel.

Comment: If you could show some sample inputs (even better - defined in code) and then the expected sample outputs then that might make it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

Group by `CodeType` first, then inside each group, group by `ConditionType, Description` and select appropriate results.

```
var results = allTypes.GroupBy(
    type => type.CodeType, // CodeType key selector
    (codeType, elements) => new TypeModel
    {
        Type = codeType,
        Conditions = elements.GroupBy(
            x => new { x.ConditionType, x.Description }, // ConditionType key selector
            x => x.QuestionType, // QuestionType selector as elements of the ConditionType group
            (condition, elements2) => new ConditionModel
            {
                Type = condition.ConditionType,
                Description = condition.Description,
                // Questions transformation
                Questions = elements2.Select(q => new QuestionModel { Type = q }).ToList()
            }).ToList()
    });
```

In case you are confused by so much nested LINQ, there is nothing wrong in using some plain old loops in order to create your resulting data:

```
var results = new List<TypeModel>();
foreach (var item in allTypes.GroupBy(type => type.CodeType))
{
    var conditionsList = new List<ConditionModel>();

    foreach (var item2 in item.GroupBy(x => new { x.ConditionType, x.Description }))
    {
        conditionsList.Add(new ConditionModel
        {
            Type = item2.Key.ConditionType,
            Description = item2.Key.Description,
            Questions = item2.Select(x => new QuestionModel { Type = x.QuestionType }).ToList()
        });
    }

    results.Add(new TypeModel
    {
        Type = item.Key,
        Conditions = conditionsList
    });
}
```